# Passing a multidimensional array between classes

Tags: c++, multidimensional-array, compiler-errors, parameter-passing

I know that you can pass a multidimensional array into a function using:

```
void Class1::foo(Bar bars[][10])
{
   // Do stuff
}
```

and that you could return a pointer to the first member in a single-dimensional array by using:

```
Bar* Clas2::getBars()
{
   return bars;  //Where bars is a member of a class
}
```

However when 'bars' is a multidimensional array, I get the error:

`Cannot convert Bar (*)[10] to Bar* in return`

Could someone clarify why this is occuring?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should write as the compiler says

```
Bar (*)[10] Clas2::getBars()
{
   return bars;  //Where bars is a member of a class
}
```

You said correctly that "you could return a pointer to the first member in a .. array". The member or more precisely element of your two dimensional array is one dimensional array of type `Bar [10]`.
The pointer to this element will look as `Bar (*)[10]`

Oh I am sorry indeed shall be as

```
Bar (* Clas2::getBars() )[10]
{
   return bars;  //Where bars is a member of a class
}
```

Or you can use typedef. For example

```
typedef Bar ( *BarPtr )[10];
BarPtr Clas2::getBars()
{
   return bars;  //Where bars is a member of a class
}
```

Comment: When I do, I get the error: "unqualified-id before ')' token, and states that getBars() returns no type.

Comment: @Xemerau I updated my post. If you used a construction from the upadted post then what is the error and what construction did you use?

Comment: The error was coming from the solution you posted before the update, using typedef fixed it though. Thanks a ton.

Answer (score 0):

You should use:

```
Bar (*Clas2::getBars())[10]
{
    return bars;  //Where bars is a member of a class
}
```

or better looking way:

```
typedef Bar (*Bar10x10ptr)[10];

Bar10x10ptr Clas2::getBars()
{
    return bars;  //Where bars is a member of a class
}
```

Comment: If I do this, i get an error indicating that 'getBars' is a declared as a function returning an array, which seems like what I wanted to do.

Comment: On GCC it works fine.
Try to test it with `int` instead of `Bar`.
Or you can try this:

    `Bar (*a)[10];
    decltype(a) Clas2::getBars()
    {
        return bars;  //Where bars is a member of a class
    }`